# Cell renderer component moving outside of an AG-grid when it is inside a mat tab

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, mat-table

I have two AG-grid displaying datas. Each of them has, at the end of each row, two icons meant to modify or suppress the data line. They each are inside of a mat tab.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Adresses">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end py-3"><button class="btn btn-major" *ngIf="modify" (click)="showCreateAdresseDialog()">CRÉER</button></div>
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="height: 600px"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        suppressCellSelection="true"
        [paginationAutoPageSize]="true"
        [pagination]="true"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
        [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
        [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Rôles">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end py-3"><button class="btn btn-major" (click)="showCreateRoleDialog()" *ngIf="modify">CRÉER</button></div>
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="height: 600px"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [rowData]="rolesRowData"
        [columnDefs]="columns"
        [gridOptions]="rolesGridOptions"
        suppressCellSelection="true"
        [paginationAutoPageSize]="true"
        [pagination]="true"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
        [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
        [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRolesRowsTemplate"
        (gridReady)="onRolesGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

Below, you may see how I added the components in the AG-grid.

```
frameworkComponents = {
    modifierButtonRenderer: ActeurModifierAdresseButtonRendererComponent,
    // Other components
};

  gridOptions = {
context: {
  parentComponent: this
},
defaultColDef: {
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  suppressMovable: true
},
columnDefs: [
  { /* some data columns */ },
  {cellRenderer: 'modifierButtonRenderer', pinned: 'right', width: 50, suppressMenu: true},
  {cellRenderer: 'supprimerButtonRenderer', pinned: 'right', width: 50, suppressMenu: true}
]
```

Now, each button is rendered inside the AG-grid. But if switch to the second mat-tab, and then go back to the first one, each cellRenderer is moved outside grid. It's not just the CSS that changed the position of the element. They moved just after the closing tag of the grid.

[Before I switch mat tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeatF.png)

[After the switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXH19.png)

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening, or how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Have a nice day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a few tests, it seems that surrounding the **<ag-grid-angular>** with a single **<div>** is sufficient to remove that bug.

Still, it is weird that putting the grid as a direct child of the **<mat-tab>** element could cause that bug.

Comment: Was about to go mad, this seems to be a problem when it is embedded in modals or other hiding components, indeed adding a div around the table made it work!

Comment: Thanks for that, the div trick saved me a few hours of confused debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much for a simple solution, saved me agony and time.